# Converting and reverting in VIM the endnote {author , #XXX} references?

Tags: vim, plugins

I am facing a problem to convert a document that has the following:

> This author {john, #99} said that ...
>   ... bla bla this other author mentioned {barlic, #1508} ...

I would like that vim convert it to :

> This author \cite{latexref99} said that ...
>   ... bla bla this other author mentioned \cite{latexref1508} ...

Any idea how to do that ? but also how to revert to :

> > This author {,#99} said that ... ... bla bla this other author mentioned {, #1508} ..

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have flagged this for migration.

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't think this is latex related

Answer (score 1):

Convert to:

```
:%s/{[^#]*#\(\d\+\)}/\\cite{latexref\1}/g
```

Convert back:

```
:%s/\\cite{latexref\(\d\+\)}/{,#\1}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a plugin you can use sed:

```
sed -e 's/{[^}]*\#\([0-9]*\)}/\\cite\{latexref\1\}/g' < file.tex >new_ref.tex
```

you also can map this to a shortcut in vim

```
nmap n :%w ! cat % \| sed -e 's/{[^}]*\#\([0-9]*\)}/\\cite\{latexref\1\}/g' > % <CR>
```